# Matplotlib: global "switch off" for plotting?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I often run experiment scripts that plot various plots and images as they process a video sequence, so that I can monitor/debug the progress. Sometimes I would like to not show the plots so that it processes the video faster. I could just add a switch in my code, but my code is changing with each experiment. So I wonder it matplotlib has itself some form of global switch off that turns off all plotting, kind of ignoring all the plotting commands.

I have tried to add this at the top of my scripts:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
if 'Agg' in os.environ:
    print("Not plotting!")
    mpl.use('Agg')
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.ioff()
else:
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.ion()
```

It doesn't plot to screen, but it's still spending time in the plotting functions, which is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://matplotlib.org/users/shell.html#controlling-interactive-updating) suggests that turning the interactive mode off should do the trick:

> The interactive property of the pyplot interface controls whether a
>   figure canvas is drawn on every pyplot command. If interactive is
>   False, then the figure state is updated on every plot command, but
>   will only be drawn on explicit calls to draw(). When interactive is
>   True, then every pyplot command triggers a draw.

Try `interactive(False)`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.interactive(False)
```

You could also monkeypatch the `.draw` and `.plot` functions:

Comment: Ok, thanks. This should work, although for me it doesn't because I typically work in interactive mode and my visualization functions have a plt.draw() at the end, so it still redraws event if interactive is False. I think it's probably easier if I add my own global switch. But I'll accept your answer.

Comment: You should not call `plt.draw()` explicitly.  In mpl 1.5+ in interactive mode it will automattically re-draw if needed and saving a figure always triggers a full re-draw.

Comment: also that doc page is very out of date :(

Comment: also you should be using the OO interface for writing your own plotting functions.